# Salesforce User Interface API is returning "The requested resource does not exist"

Tags: lightning, user-interface-api

I am able to retrieve the picklist values ( Controlling /dependent ) using the user interface api. But for one custom picklist field values are not coming through this api.

```
String method = 'GET'; 
String endpoint = String.format('/services/data/v43.0/ui-api/object-info/{0}/picklist-values/{1}', new String[]{ objectAPIName, recordTypeId }); 
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); 
request.setEndpoint('callout:UI_API_Named_Credentials'+endPoint); 
request.setMethod(method); 
HTTPResponse response = (new Http()).send(request);
```

I verified that , this particular record type has the access to that custom picklist field, and picklist values are assigned to the record type and logged in user profile has the access to custom field.

Comment: Do the current user has access to record type you are referring to? How are you calling it? Can you add the minimal required code as well?

Comment: Yes, the logged in user has the access to record type. Some sample code   
            String method = 'GET';
            String endpoint = String.format('/services/data/v43.0/ui-api/object-info/{0}/picklist-values/{1}', new String[]{ objectAPIName, recordTypeId });
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint('callout:UI_API_Named_Credentials'+endPoint);
            request.setMethod(method);
            
            HTTPResponse response = (new Http()).send(request);

Comment: Can you add debug statements and check the logs to see what your callout "endpoint" actually looks like when it hits the one picklist it errors on?

Comment: End Point : /services/data/v43.0/ui-api/object-info/Case/picklist-values/012i0000001J02KAAS In response, I am getting picklist values and dependent picklist values except one custom picklist field values.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to contain the new info. Is that URL the one that shows up for "endpoint" in a debug statement before your callout?